# Java application speed goes up after adding log output

Tags: java, performance

We stumbled upon a rather strange problem IMO. Our clients have been complaining about the speed at which our application imports and processes data from files [ filesize 1kB cca, time required to import the file under normal conditions is 4-10 seconds, depending on the overall workload. Yes, it is a lot ]...

So we started looking into it, but something quite unexpected happened: after inserting debug log outputs into certain parts of the code [ not affecting the logic otherwise ] the import sped up quite a lot : 300ms-2200ms /file depending on the overall workload.

Language used: Java

JDK 6_34 on my station [ don't know what versions my colleagues use ]

I've went through the code... many times. Nothing unusual. Even though it's all executed in a thread, this thread doesn't have a competitor doing the same job OR accessing the same files.

Is this situation familiar to anyone?

P.S.: I do hope that this question does belong here. If not, I apologize sincerely.

edit:

as for logging, we use log4j.

OS: Windows XP / my machine. One colleague has the same, the other uses Win7 /

CPU: E7500 @ 2.93 GHz

RAM: 2 GB DDR2

One other machine is basically the same. The configuration of the third is unknown to me as it's new and not my workstation.

Files are all loaded/stored from/to a local HDD in my situation.

What concerns me most is that we use a platform for which we have no source, because, well we've paid for a license, but not source >.<

Comment: That is interesting and sounds applicable to something I have seen as well.  This is a good place for such a question

Comment: You'll need to add more details about what logging framework you're using and your configuration.

Comment: Are the downloaded files / log files on a local or on a network drive? Is the time mostly spent importing the data or processing it?

Comment: Interesting. Somehow, must deepen in code/framework/libraries/resources location to get a proper answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter what speed goes up what goes down.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code?

Comment: That is the most backwards thing. I have never heard or experienced that, and I also have used log4j. Are there files that are not being closed properly and maybe the log output is forcing the underlying io subsystem to garbage collect??

Comment: @BrunoSilva My boss did in the beginning, but since the results were going strange we first decided to get more solid data... and well... ended up not really understanding what the hell is happening.

Comment: Well... the forced GC is possible. Although the memory fluctuations are lower [ before it was ranging from 130 MB-250 MB, now it's 220-235 MB, not really going above ... ] 

Also files are taken care of.

Comment: Is it possible you have hand-coded blocking operations (e.g., wait() and notify()) which have not been fully wrung out?  In these conditions, you could have processing activities blocked when there is work waiting (e.g., queued work) but a notify() is lost somewhere. Added load from logging might fool with the timing enough to make this slightly less likely to occur...

Comment: Also, could you sketch an outline/top-level pseudo code that would give a hint to the structure?  Do you have queueing/blocking?  You mention a single thread, is this the same or separate from the main() thread?  Have you tried inserting some timestamp instrumentation so you know how long segments of computation take (here handcoding some instrumentation may be less disruptive than profiling as suggested above -- profiling may well cause the same behavior as the added logging).  If you do this, you want to sock away the values somewhere rather than logging/printf'ing, obviously.

Comment: @andersoj Hm... I guess I know what I'll be looking for tomorrow >.< But I think we would have found this after the time we've spent on this. Still, we're humans, stressed, angry and we can lose concentration.  Looking once more can't hurt.

Comment: I would guess that the comment about the files residing on a network drive is worth looking at. The extra pause to do logging is maybe allowing network operations to play catchup.

Just a stab in the dark of course :P

Good luck and please post the answer when u get it all figured ot.

Comment: As I added to my first post, the data is on the HDD of my machine.

I sure will tell you, if we find anything else :)

Comment: When you are reading the files, are u using traditional IO:

BufferedInputStream(FileInputStream(file)) etc.

OR are u using the new IO and mapping the files to memory direct?

Comment: When you've earned 50 rep you'll be able to leave comments on any post, in the meantime please don't use answers for this purpose.

Comment: Ok... I forgot to mark the "Answer" to the question. Albeit it's not a solution, given that after extensive searching I was able to find nothing else and management absolutely refused to change code to work better with threads once the "logging" made up for bad synchronization... I apologize. 

Not to forget: All other answers are interesting. But since I'm not able to find the exact reason, I'm marking the Answer which seems to best explain, what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding logging adds synchronisation points to your logic. Perhaps what you are seeing is a (odd) side effect of this.

Answer (score 5):

My theory is that adding logging is changing something in your application's thread scheduling patterns.

Normally, this shouldn't matter.  But if the underlying problem in your application is something related to thread scheduling, then it is not surprising that the logging changes the observed behaviour.

I recommend that you audit the relevant parts of your codebase looking for `Thread.sleep(...)` calls, `Thread.yield()` calls, places where your code is polling, and so on.  Also consider that this might be happening in 3rd-party library code.

@OldCurmudgeon's answer includes two simple versions of what you should be looking for.  Even using `sleep(0)` is wasteful, though it is better than `sleep(N)` where `N` is significantly greater than zero.

Answer (score 4):

Were you able to reproduce the customer's original problem (i.e. Were you able to pull files and have them take 4-10 seconds as you mentioned) on a machine that you are using?

If not, then there are too many factors involved to specifically give log4j the credit. I'm with Wilf on this one. There's no way that adding logs could reliably increase the speed of a piece of code...at least there's no way that I can think of.

If you were able to reproduce the issue, then added logs, and then, using the same hardware, same logic, and same files got that much of a speed increase, then you have officially blown my mind.

Comment: Well, we changed the logging method to debug and yes, when we log only verbose, the process slows down. The whole office swore to me that they did nothing else /as I confirmed by comparing the code... I didn't really want to believe them T_T /

Comment: @user1628658: What do you mean "when we log only verbose?"

Comment: It means that the logging we added is ignored, because yesterday we decided to leave it in the code for debugging purposes in the future. And when debugging mode is off, we usually use level verbose which basically means "Print all the usual output. Nothing else."

Answer (score 4):

In this sort of situation, what I did was place trace timings at key parts of the application (say 5 - 10 stages) and see what part was taking the most time. In your case you could see what stage speeds up.  I suspect there is just one stage which will be faster in which case you can places more timing in that and narrow down to the code where you see the most difference.

In the past where you see strange increase in delay this has been down to network calls such a DNS lookups.  When you process the file, are you accessing an external application/network service?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a spin loop.

Somewhere in your code (or the underlying framework) you have code that looks something like:

```
while (!ready()) {
  // Do next to nothing.
}
```

or something that boils down to that.

Essentially the loop is spinning so fast the resource it is waiting for does not get enough time to become available. You will usually also see strangely high CPU usage.

The logging alleviates the condition because it slows down the loop, thus allowing the resource to become ready.

You need to change it to something like:

```
while (!ready()) {
  Thread.currentThread().sleep(0);
}
```

or, ideally, use a proper blocking mechanism.

Comment: Yes indeed it is ... but only almost. :) Thus my suggestion for a "proper blocking mechanism".

Comment: I searched, but frankly: It's not in our code and I have no access to framework sources, therefore I cannot verify this.